# Dynamic Spool to File name

Tags: sql, csv, plsql, sqlplus, spool

I would like to extract the same query every week in sqlplus or SQLCL, maybe scheduling the task on windows server, spooling in a csv file with the name of the account code and the date.
I wrote the following script and it works but I've two problems.

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
COL VPATH NEW_VALUE NEW_VPATH;
COL PRESIDIO NEW_VALUE NEW_PRESIDIO;
COL SEPARATORE NEW_VALUE NEW_SEPARATORE;
COL DATA NEW_VALUE NEW_DATA;
COL EXT NEW_VALUE NEW_EXT;
SET SQLFORMAT CSV;
SELECT 'C:\Shared_Folder\' VPATH, 'AO_GALLARATE' PRESIDIO,'_' SEPARATORE, TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE) DATA,'.CSV' EXT FROM DUAL;
SET FEEDBACK ON;
SET TERMOUT OFF;
SPOOL "&NEW_VPATH&NEW_PRESIDIO&NEW_SEPARATORE&NEW_DATA&NEW_EXT";
SELECT /*CSV*/ SERIAL_NUMBER, DNS_HOST_NAME, IP_ADDRESS, MODEL_NAME, TOTAL_PAGE_COUNT - COLOR_PAGE_COUNT, COLOR_PAGE_COUNT, TRUNC(LAST_DATA_COLLECTION) FROM DEVICE WHERE ACCOUNT_CODE = '&NEW_PRESIDIO' AND model_name LIKE '%MS410%';
ORDER BY SERIAL_NUMBER ASC;
SPOOL OFF;
```

1. i get a prompt requesting to enter a value for all new_vpath, new_presidio.. at least for the first time. If i remove this part, i get the request when it's supposed to start spooling
2. If i use pl/sql, i can successfully set the variables, so no prompt appears, but spooling and query are not working. actually spooling says illegal file name and query is not working for missing "account_code" string in the query.

Where and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORACLE How to use spool with dynamic spool location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246360/oracle-how-to-use-spool-with-dynamic-spool-location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably nothing.  This is a little different that what @ruudvan says is a duplicate.  You should be able to use substitution on the spool command the way you are doing it.

This was a bug in an earlier release. In the latest version of SQLcl, I've tried this and seems to work great.

```
(~/qa) $cat subnew.sql
SET ECHO  OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
COL VPATH NEW_VALUE NEW_VPATH;
COL PRESIDIO NEW_VALUE NEW_PRESIDIO;
COL SEPARATORE NEW_VALUE NEW_SEPARATORE;
COL DATA NEW_VALUE NEW_DATA;
COL EXT NEW_VALUE NEW_EXT;
COL USER NEW_VALUE NEW_USER;
SET SQLFORMAT CSV;
SELECT './' VPATH, 'AO_GALLARATE' PRESIDIO,'_' SEPARATORE, TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE) DATA,
       '.CSV' EXT , USER FROM DUAL;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET TERMOUT OFF;
SPOOL "&NEW_VPATH&NEW_PRESIDIO&NEW_SEPARATORE&NEW_DATA&NEW_EXT";
select /* csv */ * from substitution
where upper(name) = '&NEW_USER';
SPOOL OFF;
exit

(~/qa) $sql barry/oracle @subnew

SQLcl: Release 12.2.0.1.0 RC on Tue Aug 09 13:21:28 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Aug 09 2016 13:21:29 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

"VPATH","PRESIDIO","SEPARATORE","DATA","EXT","USER"
"./","AO_GALLARATE","_","09-AUG-16",".CSV","BARRY"
(~/qa) $ls -altr AO_GALLARATE_09-AUG-16.CSV 
-rw-r--r--  1 bamcgill  staff  22  9 Aug 13:21 AO_GALLARATE_09-AUG-16.CSV
(~/qa) $cat AO_GALLARATE_09-AUG-16.CSV 
"ID","NAME"
1,"Barry"
(~/qa) $
```