# Using path relative to SQL script location in that script?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-scripts

I have a sql script in

```
dir:\some\path\script.sql
```

This script is executed via SqlDeveloper and `spool`s some data into

```
dir:\some\path\data\tablename.csv
```

Now, I have to store the script in a .sql file because if I execute it from SqlDeveloper directly, `spool` writes the query itself to the file which I do not want.

But I also do not want to hard-code paths because everyone in my team has their GIT repo whereever they want, so the scenario I'd like to achieve is that my sql script uses relative paths from it's location to write the csv files.

Currently the script.sql looks something like this:

```
SET COLSEP ";"
spool dir:\some\path\data\table1.csv
select /*csv*/ * from table1;
spool off;
```

and I want to look it something like this

```
SET COLSEP ";"
spool current_dir\data\table1.csv
select /*csv*/ * from table1;
spool off;
```

So that when using the script, the path has to be typed only once, when calling the script.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define dynamic spool location? If yes then-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246360/oracle-how-to-use-spool-with-dynamic-spool-location

Comment: @JSapkota not really, as far as I understand in the question you linked part of the desired path is stored in a table. What I need is to get the location of the sql script from within the script.

Answer (score 0):

More of a workaround than a solution to the problem, but for now I just created a `scriptRunner.sql` file in the same directory as the `script.sql` which simply runs the script (`@script.sql`).

When opening this file, it seems like SqlDevelopers working directory is set to the directory where both `.sql` files are in and this property is extended to the called script, therefore I can simply use

`spool data\table1.csv`