# SQL server query to oracle conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to convert SQL server query to oracle(sql developer), its simple but still I am not able to.
Can anyone please help.
I am trying the below.

```
Declare @lsdate date
set @lsdate=(select max(Lupdate) from table1)
select * from table2 where column=@lsdate
```

also how do use spool to produce dynamic filename using this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple query as follow:

```
Select * from table2
Where column = (select max(Lupdate) from table1)
```

You can see answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246360/oracle-how-to-use-spool-with-dynamic-spool-location) for dynamic spooling

**Update**:

You can store the value from `table1` in variable and use it as the name of the `spool` file or in the second query as follows:

```
column lsdate new_value lsdate
select max(Lupdate) lsdate from table1;
spool &lsdate.my_log.log
Select * from table2 where column2 = '&lsdate';
spool off
```

Comment: Thank you Tejash, but I want to use variable since I also want to use that variable in SPOOL

Comment: Thanks a ton Tejash, that worked. Only other issue is with SPOOL, since the variable is date format I am getting the error as "filename is not valid'